# Background color will not apply to list and list item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, html-lists

I posted a photo for you to see exactly what problem I have. I don't understand why the style does not apply to the ul and li. I apply the background style to the nav-container so I believe that should be applied to every element right?

I could use a bit of help and some explanation to understand this thing.

```css
header {
  background-image: url('Logos\ and\ Assets/cover.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 10%;
  background-color: rgba(153, 217, 140, 0.3);
}

.nav-ul-2 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-ul-2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0% 20px;
}

.nav-ul-1 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-ul-1 li {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-ul-1 li:hover {
  color: yellowgreen;
}

.nav-ul-2 li {
  [enter image description here][1] transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-ul-2 li:hover {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="nav-container">
    <ul class="nav-ul-1">
      <li>Acasa</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="nav-ul-2">
      <li>Servicii</li>
      <li>Despre Noi</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div>
      <img src="Logos and Assets/roFlag.svg" class="flag" alt="ro-flag">
      <img src="Logos and Assets/englFlag.svg" class="flag" alt="eng-flag">
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: Applying the background-color to the containing div will apply it to that DIV and will fill up to however much space the inner elements are taking up

Comment: Instead of applying the background color to the `.nav-container`, apply it to the `.nav-ul-1` & `.nav-ul-2` elements

Comment: Your [mcve] does NOT demonstrate the problem. I suspect you have extra CSS that has a background applied to the lists.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understant exactly what you are trying here because
your navigation seems to me like this with background color :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Typically your containers are going to be div elements that surround certain areas of the page (a nav-container, a .container for the whole body element, etc.) Try using a div to wrap your nav element and apply your background style to it.

Comment: You should copy the snippet from the question and make modifications to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!